# XSLT in Chrome extension: Unsafe attempt to load URL

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension which should apply XSLT transform to certain XML documents on the fly. Just for testing I use the following XML and XSL files:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<WebServiceMessage>
 <status>timeout</status>
 <message>Nameserver%2520not%2520registered.</message>
 <stepName>Finish</stepName>
 <stepNumber>11</stepNumber>
 <maxStepNumber>11</maxStepNumber>
 <percent>100</percent>
 <session>2fc0f139b88a800151e5f21b9d747919</session>
</WebServiceMessage>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html><head></head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <p><b><xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/></b>:
      <span><xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/></xsl:attribute><xsl:value-of select="."/></span></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The tranfromation works normally if it's linked inside a test XML file itself, that is via:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="message.xsl"?>
```

The extension should inject the same xsl link into XML-files.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js" : ["contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources":
  [
    "message.xsl"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**contentscript.js:**

```js
(function()
{
  if(document.xmlVersion != null)
  {
     var e = document.createProcessingInstruction(
               "xml-stylesheet",
               "type='text/xsl' href='" + chrome.extension.getURL("message.xsl") + "'");
     document.insertBefore(e, document.firstChild);
  }
})();
```

**The problem**

Chrome outputs the following error into console:

*Unsafe attempt to load URL `chrome-extension://ladfinoepkgipbeooknnklpakoknohjh/message.xsl` from frame with URL `http://localhost/out.xml`. Domains, protocols and ports must match.*

How to fix this? I saw some reports on the Internet related to similar errors, which seems like a bug in Chrome.

I placed the xsl-file on the web-server as well, and changed styleheet link to the web-server. Still the same error:

*Unsafe attempt to load URL `http://localhost/message.xsl` from frame with URL `http://localhost/out.xml`. Domains, protocols and ports must match.*

Apparently domains, protocols, and ports **do match**.

Comment: I guess it is a [security feature of chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html).

Comment: I used this code without any problem, maybe it's only when you update the `window.document` that it does it: `var documentString = document.firstChild.innerHTML; var docu = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<xml>'+documentString+'</xml>', application/xml"); var e = docu.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='" + chrome.extension.getURL("message.xsl") + "'"); docu.insertBefore(e, docu.firstChild);`

Comment: @jjperezaguinaga  You have created a new document instead of existing one. In a sense, this is the same as a workaround I posted below.

Comment: Yeah. How that has been working so far for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a workaround I'm currently using:

```js
function loadXMLtext(url)
{
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xhttp.send();
  if(xhttp.responseXML == undefined) throw "XHR failed for " + url;
  return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function transformxml()
{
  var xml = loadXMLtext(document.location.href);
  var xsl = loadXMLtext(chrome.extension.getURL("message.xsl"));

  var xsltPrs = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltPrs.importStylesheet(xsl);

  var result = xsltPrs.transformToFragment(xml, document);

  var xmlsrv = new XMLSerializer();
  var plaintext = xmlsrv.serializeToString(result);
  document.documentElement.innerHTML = plaintext;
}

transformxml();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a webpage to process a resource outside its domain. You can try to "trick" the browser through localhost, but this is the same as asking facebook to execute a script from google. This is a [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) error and **to solve it just move the processing from the content script to a background/event page**. You will need to [pass](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) the result after processing, but that's the correct approach.

Another reason why most processing should be done in a background/event page is in order to optimize your extension, otherwise you are just using the current `window` engine, and if it blocks, so it does the tab for the user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some thoughts. 1) Extensions' permissions in manifest must override policies for external sites - otherwise, entire concept of extensions permissions is useless (such thing as `<all_urls>` etc. would be void, and might not exist at all). 2) I mentioned that even if XSL is hosted on the same domain, the error remains. Also, I can't agree about moving processing into background page - this brings too much useless overheads, and again voids existence of content scripts, which are very useful tool for "in page" processing, and it should be used when appropriate.

Comment: You are right, just loaded knockoutjs through ajax in a content script (and I'm not even asking for permission to `http://knockoutjs.com/` in my manifest). Isn't the permissions and CSP for your extension, not the webpage's? The same domain is localhost, so I'm not sure about it, try playing with your `/etc/hosts` and change 127.0.0.1 to a domain you wanna test. And with the new [events pages](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/event_pages.html) it's not an overhead at all, although the API is still in dev.

Comment: Changing localhost and local IPs to a faked domain from `hosts` does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this locally using Chrome's command line flags.

The specific flag is `--allow-file-access-from-files`

```
On OS X: from Terminal.app run /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files

On Windows: from the command prompt run C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files (replacing USERNAME with your username)
```

Note: You will probably have to quit Chrome if it is currently running otherwise session. make sure about this.